# not able to display in HTML while using FireFox

Tags: html

I am not able to show an image in Firefox when using the `img` tag. In IE it's working as expected. Why is this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>      
                    <img border="0" src="D:\Pictures\sam.JPG" alt="wiki" width="500" height="1"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display an image from your computer on an external host?

Comment: no josh. i am using it  locally. it is just sample. i was trying to work with image in  html.

Comment: Is it Simple HTML or Serverside scripts like JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way of referencing an image on local disk would be

```
file:///D:/Pictures/sam.JPG
```

But you will never see the image anyway - you're setting its `height="1"`

Comment: but i am getting it in IE browser and not in firefox

Comment: this means that IE and Firefox behave differently